# HTML5 form validation: Default = invalid, is this normal behavior?

Tags: forms, html, validation

I am building a form using HTML5 form validation.
I have the CSS classes `input:valid` and `input:invalid` defined. Some of the input fields are marked as `required`, but not all of them. Is it normal that the fields that aren't marked as `required` are valid by default, meaning in my case have a green background? And is it normal that `required` fields are invalid by default?

If this is normal: Why did they make it that way? In my eyes it is not very user friendly to mark a field as `valid` oder `invalid` before something was entered. Is there anything I can do *besides* JavaScript?

Comment: You're right. This is very bad UX as users are first "punished" with their invalid fields. Doesn't matter whether fields are required or not. The usual behaviour should be un-validated by default and validated on field blur (and form submit) or on keystroke. We should have the ability to choose validation behaviour. It's also stupid to see email field being invalid while typing into it. I really don't like this behaviour because even though they implemented it we still have to use Javascript plugins.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik yeah, who are these people who let things like this get out the door? I just spent an hour reviewing html5 form validation for a project, and now I realize I just wasted an hour.  there is no html5 validation, only a weak attempt at beginning to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal behaviour. Whenever user entered anything or not, he should know that field, marked as required, will be invalid until he will enter anything that matches pattern (or just anything :) ).

If for some reason you don't like such behaviour - sorry, but you should use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Then I'll just cope with it i think.